# Trigger Custom jQuery Event and delay it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to trigger the event of an element being removed from the DOM. Sadly I must use the original `.remove()`, because it is being called from an external script. So I extended jQuery in order to catch the event:

```
var oldRemove = $.fn.remove;
$.fn.remove = function(){
    this.trigger('remove');
    return oldRemove.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

This works fine. I can use it like this:

```
$('ul').find('li').on('remove', function(e){
    console.log('EVENT REGGED');
});
```

I want to **use this code to highlight the deletion of elements**. An example: Set the color of the element to red, wait 2 seconds and then delete it.

What is the most elegant way to do this? I already experimented with `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation` or to return something from the trigger, but nothing worked.

Here's a fiddle so you can test it: http://jsfiddle.net/xahthnjz/

What can I do in order to first highlight the element and then delay the deletion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a setTimeout within your custom jQuery function to handle the removal of the item after applying the color change. I've made an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mkjj94m1/2/

I've renamed the function to `deleteItem` as `remove` is an existing jQuery function.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I cannot control the name of the originally called method. `.remove()` is always called by another script. I need to trigger exactly this method. Than you anyway! :)